# configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals

Tags: r, fedora, failed-installation

I am trying to install R-3.1.1 on Fedora 20.
The "make" gives me the following warning

> configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Briefly:

1. You probably need the `texinfo` command, cf the [R Installation and Administration
   manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html).
2. Fedora should have binaries in a repo as well.  [Question 2.6 of the R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Are-there-Unix_002dlike-binaries-for-R_003f) mentions

> R binaries for Fedora, maintained by Tom “Spot” Callaway, are provided
>   as part of the Fedora distribution and can be accessed through yum,
>   the RPM installer/updater. Note that the “Software” application
>   (gnome-software), which is the default GUI for software installation
>   in Fedora 20, cannot be used to install R. It is therefore recommended
>   to use the yum command line tool.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did a search on Google and unable to find it. After I posted though I found one with answer. Also, I was installing using the R Installation and Administration manual. Did not occur to check that. With Find "texinfo" I found the packages for this and two other packages for 2 more warnings. Thanks again.

Comment: I had earlier checked with yum list available. Obviously there were too many and I was unable to narrow to find it. Thanks for this info.

Comment: The pre-built versions are R-core and R-devel, as mentioned in the R-FAQ from cran. Also, there is an R and R-core-devel. I will install with yum later today.

Comment: For the HTML versions: `apt-get install texinfo` , if you also want the pdf versions: `sudo apt-get install texlive` and `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` then run `./configure` again

Comment: Or, if on Debian/Ubuntu, do what the package does: `sudo apt-get build-dep r-base`.  Easier _and_ more precise (but need `src-deb` entries, which are worth it).

Comment: On Fedora `sudo dnf install texinfo`